# Error: Cannot Find Symbol

Tags: java

Okay, so I'm very new to Java, and I have no prior programming experience. I'm going through the Java tutorial, and everything is going alright until I run into a problem in the "Objects" section the tutorial.

The title of the program is Create Object Demo. The goal is to find the width, height, and area of one rectangle, and the new position of another. You do all of this using the premise of "Creating an object." The creating the object part is the problem.

Here's the original code:

```
public class CreateObjectDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Declare and create a point object and two rectangle objects.
    Point originOne = new Point(23, 94);
    Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle(originOne, 100, 200);
    Rectangle rectTwo = new Rectangle(50, 100);

    // display rectOne's width, height, and area
    System.out.println("Width of rectOne: " + rectOne.width);
    System.out.println("Height of rectOne: " + rectOne.height);
    System.out.println("Area of rectOne: " + rectOne.getArea());

    // set rectTwo's position
    rectTwo.origin = originOne;

    // display rectTwo's position
    System.out.println("X Position of rectTwo: " + rectTwo.origin.x);
    System.out.println("Y Position of rectTwo: " + rectTwo.origin.y);

    // move rectTwo and display its new position
    rectTwo.move(40, 72);
    System.out.println("X Position of rectTwo: " + rectTwo.origin.x);
    System.out.println("Y Position of rectTwo: " + rectTwo.origin.y);
}
}
```

I run the program, and this is my error message:

```
CreateObjectDemo:.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
       Point originOne = new Point(23, 94);
       ^ 

symbol: class Point
location: class CreateObjectDemo
CreatObjectDemo.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
    Point originOne = new Point(23, 94);
                          ^
```

The full code and process is also located [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objects.html)

Likewise, the error message points to the word "Point" and "Rectangle" in the same fashion and claims that it "cannot find [the] symbol."

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been struggling with this error for a couple of days now. Thanks.

Comment: You need to download the Point and Rectangle classes (in the link that you specified), add `import` statements as appropriate, and then include them in your classpath when you compile. That particular error is the compiler saying, "Wait, you're referencing these classes but I don't know what they are!"

Comment: Nobody leaves the room! Who got the symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Roddy suggests, you need to download and include the `Point` and `Rectangle` classes in the tutorial you are following.  If you place those classes in the same directory as your `CreateObjectDemo` you'll not need import statements.

Exactly what's happening is the compiler is trying to convert your Java source code into byte code which the JVM (Java Virtual Machine) can interpret.  For code to compile, all classes must be found. As the `Point` and `Rectangle` classes cannot be found, your code can't compile. Class `Point` and `Rectangle` are referred to as dependencies of class `CreateObjectDemo` for this reason.  `CreateObjectDemo` won't work without them, it is dependent on `Point` and `Rectangle`.

Fixing this is easy, just make sure your `CreateObjectDemo` class knows where the `Point` and `Rectangle` classes are.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to import the classes `Point` and  `Rectangle` to your class. Add the following two lines on the top of your class, after the `package` line.

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
```

If you are using Eclipse then just do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>, this will import the required classes for you.

Comment: I would probably just `import java.awt.*;` and be done with it.

Comment: No, I made the same mistake. He's following a demo which is using a custom Point and rectangle class. It may be that the awt point and rectangle will work, but may not. he needs to download the other classes to follow the tutorial precisely, as suggested by Roddy in comments.

Comment: the shortcut neo suggests will import the exact class types required @Bohemian also importing a specific class type makes the dependencies easier to see.

Comment: Thanks @WilliamMorrison. I assumed it is the `awt` classes the OP is referring to.

Comment: Sorry @tbodt, the shortbut in Eclipse is `Ctrl + Shift + O`, I made a typo. Corrected now.

Comment: Can you please specify which line is the package line?

Comment: You don't have a package line in this code, its in the `default` package (a place code goes when its not in any package.) All you need to do is download classes Point and Rectangle and place them in the same directory as CreateObjectsDemo @TylerRobinson

Comment: In NetBeans, it is Ctrl+Shift+I.

Comment: @TylerRobinson, the package line normally comes as the first line in a java class. But as WilliamMorrison mentioned, I dont see a package line in your class as it is using the default package.

Comment: @TylerRobinson please select an answer to close the question. Doesn't matter which to me personally, just keeps things nice and neat for OCD folks like myself :)

Comment: Agree with you @WilliamMorrison :-)

Answer (score 0):

For the CreateObject Demo there are two other classes in the tutorial you need to put in the same directory as the demo: the Point Class, and the Rectangle Class. They are described a couple of paragraphs down from the code of the demo.

So in netbeans and eclipse, put them in the same directory as CreateObjectDemo.java.

So in netbeans, go to File->New File->Java->Java Class->Class Name: Point etc

You do not need to import anything.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial is not learning about GUI but just showing how to calculate the rectangle area using a method, so it is not necessary to import java.awt in the CreateObjectDemo.class. Just make sure that the Point and Rectangle classes are put in the same package with the CreateObjectDemo class, the error will surely disappear.